# How to wait for image to load before setting scope in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, cytoscape.js

I'm using AngularJS and TypeScript. I am using the cytoscape library with the extension cytoscape-edgehandles and the wrapper ngCytoscape for AngularJS. I am trying to add an image to the hover handle of the nodes, however the implementation of the drawImage method in cytoscape-edgehandles 2.7.1 does not wait for the image to load before drawing, therefore a range error occurs.

I have tried to give the cytoscape graph the options after the image is loaded, however the cytoscape graph expects the options to immediately be available for use. So somehow I need to load the image before passing it to the graph.

In the constructor of the controller:

```
this.$scope.ehOptions = this.GetEhOptions();
```

The get EhOptions method:

```
protected GetEhOptions(): GraphModels.EhOptions {
    var options = new GraphModels.EhOptions;

    var img = new Image();
    img.width = 25;
    img.height = 25
    img.src = "../../Content/icons/ic_circle_add_24px.svg";
    options.handleImage = img;
    img.addEventListener('load', e => {
          return options;
    });
}
```

This results in the options never being loaded by the graph. If I do this in stead, I get all the options, except the image:

```
var options = new GraphModels.EhOptions;

var img = new Image();
img.width = 25;
img.height = 25
img.src = "../../Content/icons/ic_circle_add_24px.svg";

img.addEventListener('load', e => {
   options.handleImage = img;
});
return options;
```

The code of cytoscape-edgehandles concerning the handleIcon:

```js
if(options().handleIcon){
    var icon = options().handleIcon;
    var width = icon.width*cy.zoom(), height = icon.height*cy.zoom();
    ctx.drawImage(icon, hx-(width/2), hy-(height/2), width, height);
}
```

If it is changed to this, then it works:

```js
if (true) {
    var img = new Image();
    var width = 25 * cy.zoom();
    var height = 25 * cy.zoom();
    img.width = width;
    img.height = height
    img.src = "../../Content/icons/ic_circle_add_24px.svg";
    img.addEventListener('load', e => {
        ctx.drawImage(img, hx - (width/2), hy - (height/2), width, height)
    })
}
```

However, I cannot change the library code.

Hope you have any ideas. Thanks!

Comment: provide a Stackblitz example if can

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create an AngularJS promise:

```ts
protected GetEhOptions(): GraphModels.EhOptions {

    var deferred = $q.defer();
    var options = new GraphModels.EhOptions;           
    var img = new Image();

    img.width = 25;
    img.height = 25
    img.src = "../../Content/icons/ic_circle_add_24px.svg";
    options.handleImage = img;
    img.addEventListener('load', e => {
         ̶r̶e̶t̶u̶r̶n̶ ̶o̶p̶t̶i̶o̶n̶s̶;̶
         deferred.resolve(options);
    });
    img.addEventListener('error', e => {
         deferred.reject(e);
    });

    return deferred.promise;
}
```

Then extract the options from the returned promise:

```
this.GetEhOptions().then(options => {
  this.$scope.ehOptions = options;
});
```

For more information, see

- [AngularJS $q Service API Reference - The Deferred API](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q#the-deferred-api)

Answer (score 0):

I don't have any idea about cytoscape, but try this,

```
options:any = new GraphModels.EhOptions;
let globleThis = this;

var img = new Image();
img.width = 25;
img.height = 25
img.src = "../../Content/icons/ic_circle_add_24px.svg";
this.options.handleImage = img;

img.addEventListener('load', e => {
   this.GetEhOptions(globleThis.options);
});

protected GetEhOptions(options): GraphModels.EhOptions {
   return options;
}
```

or

```
var options = new GraphModels.EhOptions;

var img = new Image();
img.width = 25;
img.height = 25
img.src = "../../Content/icons/ic_circle_add_24px.svg";

img.addEventListener('load', e => {
   return options.handleImage = img;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

No experiance with a specific library but I worked with similar ones. In those cases I wrapped it into my own directive and then controlled the creation from there directly. In that case you have access to the $element and you can create it on the fly.